# How to sort RailsAdmin dropdown (while editing an object)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am using RailsAdmin gem and if my model has belongs_to association. It shows a dropdown.

This dropdown is searchable, but it's not sorted.

Is there a way to sort it?

I saw a way to sort column for railsadmin list. However, I haven't seen a way to sort a dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, the only way to order the records in the drop down, is by configuring the rails_admin list of the model with the has_many association. For example:

```
class Thing
  belongs_to :thing_category
end

class ThingCategory
  has_many :things

  rails_admin do
    list do
      sort_by :column_name
    end
  end

end
```

Unfortunately, that orders both the list view (in the dashboard), and the drop down. I'm not sure there's a way around that.

More info here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List